# Not able to print git tag ref using AzurePowerShell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, git-tag

I have a YAML file in which I checkout a repository using git tag as follows:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo-name
    type: git
    name: name
    ref: refs/tags/2.0.2304.190


variables:
  tools.ref: $[ resources.repositories['repo-name'].ref ]
```

I'm able to print the ref by using bash but not using AzurePowerShell task. What am I missing?

```
        - bash: |
            echo "Tag value: $TOOLS_REF"
          displayName: 'Echo tag value'

        - task: AzurePowerShell@4
          displayName: 'Check Git Tag'
    
          inputs:
              azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
              scriptType: inlineScript
              inline: |                 
                
                Write-Host "Tag value: $TOOLS_REF"
```

Comment: For PowerShell, if should be `$env:TOOLS_REF`, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#access-variables-through-the-environment).